# React import background image

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

Trying to import a jpeg image to use as my background in React, but keep getting error msg

```
Error: Can't resolve '/img/dots.jpeg' in 'D:\Developer\mysite\src'
```

My App.css

```
.App {
  text-align: center;
  background-image: url('/img/dots.jpeg');
}
```

My App.js

```
import './App.css';

function App() {
  return (
      <div className="App" >
          <h1>asdasdasd</h1>
      </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

My project structure:

[image: My project structure]

My understanding is as long as the image is in the src folder I can access it relatively through URL(). Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: how about replacing from  background-image: url('/img/dots.jpeg'); to  background-image: url('./img/dots.jpeg');

Comment: Yup, that fixed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/img/dots.jpeg` is indicating that it's in the root of your project, whereas `./img/dots.jpeg` will indicate that the `img` directory is in the same directory as the `App.css` file.

Comment: Thanks that fixed it. Can you explain why the dot makes a difference?

Comment: The dot represents the current directory: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(computing)#Absolute_and_relative_paths

Answer (score 0):

You can use [module-resolver](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-module-resolver) plugin and update your babel config with

```
{
  "plugins": [
    ["module-resolver", {
      "root": ["./src"],
      "alias": {
        "test": "./test",
        "underscore": "lodash"
      }
    }]
  ]
}
```

#same configuration available in the link. Then you can refer your image with complete path

Answer (score 0):

it seems there is wrong in importing the file in your css,

you are not telling the exact position to look for the file

```
.App {
    text-align: center;
    background-image: url('/img/dots.jpeg');
}
```

add these above lines it will solve the problem